# Pasar una variable de una página a otra en PHP

Tags: php

Quisiera pasar una variable extraída de una base de datos de una página a otra

**Ejemplo:**

`<?php echo $areap;  ?>`

Supongamos que este es un dato extraído de a `DB` y mostrado en la página, lo que quiero hacer es pasar esa misma variable a otra página.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para pasar `variables` de una página a otra tienes dos formas de hacerlo, la primera y la más recomendada en caso de que necesites mantener el valor siempre, seria almacenando el valor de tu `variable` en una *variable de sesión*.

*Pagina 1*

```
$_SESSION['arepa'] = $areap;
```

*Pagina 2*

```
 $areap = $_SESSION['arepa'];
```

La segunda opción sería creando una `URL` bajo el método `GET`.

*Ejemplo:*

`pagina2.php?areap=$areap`

Comment: gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @LuisMiguelVidalGarcia por favor emite un voto positivo para esta respuesta si te ha resultado util. Considera aceptarla si resuelve el problema planteado.